# Refactoring Overloaded simple Methods in Java

Tags: java, methods, overloading

I am quite new to Java. I have tried searching for an answer but can't quite seem to find one that I can completely understand.

So, I am aware of what an overloaded method is -- but how would I go about refactoring it to make it look less smelly?

say I had an overloaded method that looked like this

```
public static int subtract(int a, int b) {return a-b}
public static int subtract(int a, int b, int c) {return a-b-c}
public static int subtract(int a, int b, int c, int d) {return a-b-c-d}
```

and so on.

What would be an example of one way to refactor this? Please be detailed as I really want to learn how  it would work.

Thank you

Comment: I don't see why your method would need refactoring...

Answer (score 1):

The best seems to use [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html), it'll handle any amount of parameters (minimum 2)

```
public static int subtract(int a, int... others) {
    return a - Arrays.stream(others).sum();
}


subtract(1, 2)             // -1
subtract(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) // -19
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the patterns seems to be subtracting all subsequent inputs from each input, I might suggest that you refactor to a single method which accepts an array:

```java
public static int subtract(int[] inputs) {
    if (Objects.isNull(inputs) || inputs.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null input, returning");
    }

    int result = inputs[0];
    for (int i=1; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
        result -= inputs[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You might need a `length == 0` check

Comment: @Lino Answer updated, though I might actually prefer to use an Apache library to make a single method call checking for not null and not empty.